# What is the use of applying Design patterns in javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I started learning Design patterns. And i learned about *Module Design pattern* in javascript. Which provides object oriented capabilites like functionality (*Private and Public variables*) in javascript. One thing is that, why i should make the variables as private or public. Since even a novice developer can see the javascript code in applications and even he can access and see those variables using ***breakpoints*** in the browser tools such as inpect elements?

Comment: seeing vs being able to modify are different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use private and public patterns it can reduce future errors. The more you code the more you will realize how useful it is

Also some people like to utilize private functions to code things that they don't want to be out in the top-level global scope like email addresses for example

Answer (score 2):

The primary purpose of the Module pattern is to control variable scope rather than dumping things into the global namespace.